# How to sum(case when then) in SparkSQL DataFrame just like sql？

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to SparkSQL, and I want to calculate the percentage in my data with every status.
Here is my data like below:

```
A   B
11  1
11  3
12  1
13  3
12  2
13  1
11  1
12  2
```

So，I can do it in SQL like this:

```sql
select (C.oneTotal / C.total)   as onePercentage,
       (C.twoTotal / C.total)   as twotPercentage,
       (C.threeTotal / C.total) as threPercentage
from (select count(*) as total,
             A,
             sum(case when B = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as oneTotal,
             sum(case when B = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as twoTotal,
             sum(case when B = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as threeTotal
      from test
      group by A) as C;
```

But in the SparkSQL DataFrame, first I calculate totalCount in every status like below:

```
// wrong code
val cc = transDF.select("transData.*").groupBy("A")
      .agg(count("transData.*").alias("total"),
        sum(when(col("B") === "1", 1)).otherwise(0)).alias("oneTotal")
        sum(when(col("B") === "2", 1).otherwise(0)).alias("twoTotal")
```

The problem is the sum(when)'s result is zero.
[image]

Do I have wrong use with it? 
How to implement it in SparkSQL just like my above SQL? And then calculate the portion of every status?

Thank you for your help. In the end, I solve it with sum(when).  below is my current code.

```
val cc = transDF.select("transData.*").groupBy("A")
      .agg(count("transData.*").alias("total"),
        sum(when(col("B") === "1", 1).otherwise(0)).alias("oneTotal"),
        sum(when(col("B") === "2", 1).otherwise(0)).alias("twoTotal"))
      .select(col("total"),
        col("A"),
        col("oneTotal") / col("total").alias("oneRate"),
        col("twoTotal") / col("total").alias("twoRate"))
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please don't post code in images, add it to your post.

Comment: you check `A` for being 1 or 2, you need to check col `B`, i.e. `sum(when(col("B")==="1")`

Comment: @Andrew I am sorry about that, I changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `sum(when(...` or also `count(when..`, the second option being shorter to write:

```
val df = Seq(
  (11, 1),
  (11, 3),
  (12, 1),
  (13, 3),
  (12, 2),
  (13, 1),
  (11, 1),
  (12, 2)
).toDF("A", "B")

df
  .groupBy($"A")
  .agg(
    count("*").as("total"),
    count(when($"B"==="1",$"A")).as("oneTotal"),
    count(when($"B"==="2",$"A")).as("twoTotal"),
    count(when($"B"==="3",$"A")).as("threeTotal")
  )
  .select(
    $"A",
    ($"oneTotal"/$"total").as("onePercentage"),
    ($"twoTotal"/$"total").as("twoPercentage"),
    ($"threeTotal"/$"total").as("threePercentage")
  )
  .show()
```

gives

```
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|  A|     onePercentage|     twoPercentage|   threePercentage|
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+
| 12|0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|               0.0|
| 13|               0.5|               0.0|               0.5|
| 11|0.6666666666666666|               0.0|0.3333333333333333|
+---+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

alternatively, you could produce a "long" table with window-functions:

```
df
  .groupBy($"A",$"B").count()
  .withColumn("total",sum($"count").over(Window.partitionBy($"A")))
  .select(
    $"A",
    $"B",
    ($"count"/$"total").as("percentage")
  ).orderBy($"A",$"B")
  .show()

+---+---+------------------+
|  A|  B|        percentage|
+---+---+------------------+
| 11|  1|0.6666666666666666|
| 11|  3|0.3333333333333333|
| 12|  1|0.3333333333333333|
| 12|  2|0.6666666666666666|
| 13|  1|               0.5|
| 13|  3|               0.5|
+---+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you give multiple ways to solve it. I solved it refers to your example.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood you want to implement the logic like above sql showed in the question.

one way is like below example

```
package examples

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object AggTest extends App {
  val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
  logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)


  val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(getClass.getName)
    .master("local[*]").getOrCreate

  import spark.implicits._

  val df = Seq(
    (11, 1),
    (11, 3),
    (12, 1),
    (13, 3),
    (12, 2),
    (13, 1),
    (11, 1),
    (12, 2)
  ).toDF("A", "B")

  df.show(false)
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("test")
  spark.sql(
    """
      |select (C.oneTotal / C.total)   as onePercentage,
      |       (C.twoTotal / C.total)   as twotPercentage,
      |       (C.threeTotal / C.total) as threPercentage
      |from (select count(*) as total,
      |             A,
      |             sum(case when B = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as oneTotal,
      |             sum(case when B = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as twoTotal,
      |             sum(case when B = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as threeTotal
      |      from test
      |      group by A) as C
    """.stripMargin).show


}
```

Result :

```
+---+---+
|A  |B  |
+---+---+
|11 |1  |
|11 |3  |
|12 |1  |
|13 |3  |
|12 |2  |
|13 |1  |
|11 |1  |
|12 |2  |
+---+---+

+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|     onePercentage|    twotPercentage|    threPercentage|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
|0.3333333333333333|0.6666666666666666|               0.0|
|               0.5|               0.0|               0.5|
|0.6666666666666666|               0.0|0.3333333333333333|
+------------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: I am sorry for my bad post, Thank for your solution, it worked.